# Check if function is analytical or not

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

I cannot say that it is too difficult but I have some doubts. there are two functions and I must check if it is fits Cauchy-Riemann conditions:

$w = \frac{1}{z}$ and $w = |z|^2$

Well, I learned conditions:

$$\begin{cases} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} \\ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} =  -\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} \end{cases}$$

What I did:

$$w = \frac{1}{z} \rightarrow w = \frac{1}{x+iy} \rightarrow w =\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{iy}$$

Which means $$\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{y^2}   \\ 0 = 0\end{cases} $$

Can imaginary and real parts be devided in two fractions like I did and am I right at all?

---

With $w = |z|^2$ I am a little bit confused:

$$w = ({\sqrt{x+iy}})^2 \rightarrow w = x+iy$$

$$\begin{cases} 1 = 1 \\ 0 = - 0 \end{cases}$$

Is this right?

Comment: there is a brutal break of fraction there that I don't understand.

Comment: @GuyFsone, well, I read somewhere in the books that imaginary and real part can be devided like that, but I am not sure about that, yes

Comment: I believe such serious book does not exist. otherwise mathematics will died very soon

Comment: @AnotherDoe Which book?

Answer (score 0):

You're complex algebra is note quite right. Here are a couple of algebraic corrections which should help you get started.

It is not the case that

$$
\frac{1}{x+iy} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{iy}
$$

Rather, the correct technique is to multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate

$$
\frac{1}{x+iy} = \frac{1}{x+iy} \cdot \frac{x-iy}{x-iy} = \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}
$$

The modulus of $z = x + iy$ is defined to be $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ so $|z|^2 = x^2 + y^2 \ne x + iy$.

Critically, just because you've moved to complex variables, the laws of algebra haven't changed that much from real-valued algebra (e.g. $1/(x+y) \ne 1/x + 1/y$ in general). So try and be careful and really make sure you're following the definitions of all the terms.

Comment: oops, indeed I treated $z$ as real number and applied just roots rules

Comment: but how should i prepare the fraction to check the conditions, what would real and imaginary parts be here?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, first of you need to check the CR-conditions like you are doing. But here are some tricks to get you starting on the next part.

You can multiply the denumerator and the numerator by the conjugate of the denominator, and then use the rule that ($\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{c} $) to split the end result into a real part and an imaginary part.

$$\frac{1}{x+iy} =\frac{1}{x+iy}\cdot \frac{x-iy}{x-iy} = \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} - i \cdot \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$

I also got a video here for you if you would like to see some examples with solutions to these kinds of problems: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41pu051ZJAo